# How to get html of CKEDITOR textarea on keyup event in jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to get html of CKEDITOR textarea html content.

```
<textarea id="description" name="description" class="form-control" value="Test Description" rows="8">Test Description</textarea>

<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.9.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace("description", {toolbar: 'Basic', height: 200});

    $('#description').keyup(function () {
        var tmp = CKEDITOR.instances['description'].getData();
        $('#jobDescPreview').html(tmp);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    CKEDITOR.instances['description'].on("change",function () {
        var tmp = CKEDITOR.instances['description'].getData();

        $('#jobDescPreview').html(tmp.trim());
    });
```